# How to deploy Spring boot backend and Angular 6 frontend application in an apache Tomcat8 server?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, tomcat, angular-cli

I have developed an application with spring boot backend and angular 6 front end and everything is perfect.

But the only problem I have, is how to deploy the backend and frontend on a server apache and how frontend and backend communicate?

I have my dist for angular and the war for spring and I put them on apache, but when I click on dist, the page login appears but I don't have connection with backend.

How do I do it ?

Please help me.

Thank you :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Would you please first learn to format your question properly? [How to format your code properly in OS](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). It's really NOT easy to read your question.

Comment: @Hearen I have developed an application with spring boot backend and angular 6 front end and everything is perfect. But the only problem i have, is how to deploy the backend and frontend on a server apache and how frontend and backend communicate ? i have my dist for angular and the war for spring and i put them on apache, but when i click on dist, the page login appears but i don't have connexion with backend. How i do it ? Please help me. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to have communication between backend and frontend, you need to use CORS filters in your web.xml file which allows you to communicate from any server(since angular project runs on a different port).Below is the code of CORS Filters,try to add it to your web.xml file and check.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,authorization,serviceUrl,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Last-Modified</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```